# Gambling app - React Native vs App Store review guideline

Tags: react-native, app-store, mac-app-store

I would like to make a sport betting app with lotteries with access to real money gaming in **React Native.** Is it possible to store it in the App Store? Because it's gambling app and apple has some rules (link below)

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#third-party-software

The point 4.7 including 4.7.1 and 4.7.2.

Is React Native app considered as html5 site because of React or is considered as a native app because components are compiled partly to native iOS?

I would like to know if App Store approves react native gambling apps.

Comment: Probably not suited for Stackoverflow as it concerns internal practice of Apple. StackOverflow is for programming related questions, and seeing as though we're all programmers and not lawyers we can't really give you good advice on what Apple means with the exact wording of their guidelines.

Comment: Sidenote: All apps are considered as native, whether they are compiled or interpreted.